# Let $(R, P)$ be a local ring. If $M$ is a finitely presented module, then $M$ is flat iff $\mathrm{Tor}_{1}^R(M,R/P)=0$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

> Let $(R, P)$ be a local ring. If $M$ is a finitely presented module, then $M$ is flat iff $\mathrm{Tor}_{1}^R(M,R/P)=0$.

First, choose a minimal set of generators for $M$, and use these we can define a map from a free module $F$ onto $M$, let $K$ be the kernel, since $M$ is finitely presented, $K$ is finitely generated. Now, tensor with $R/P$, if  $\mathrm{Tor}_{1}^R(M,R/P)=0$, I want to show $K=0$, then we are done. If $\mathrm{Tor}_{1}^R(M,R/P)=0$, we have a short exact sequence

$0\longrightarrow K\otimes R/P\longrightarrow F\otimes R/P\longrightarrow M\otimes R/P\longrightarrow0$

Is it true by counting the numbers of generators with Nakayama's lemma to deduce that $K=0$ ?

Since we can view all those tensor products as vector spaces over the field $R/P$, the short exact sequence above splits, therefore the consequence follows directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can deduce that $K = 0$.

As you propose, chose a minimal set $\{ m_1, \dots, m_k \}$ of generators. Then, by **Nayakama's lemma** you obtain a **basis** for $M \otimes R/P \simeq M/PM$. (It is a classical result that minimal generating sets of finitely generated module $M$ over a local ring $(R,P)$ are in bijection with basis of the $R/P$-vector space $M/PM$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma) for example in Consequences, Local rings ; it is one of the many forms (or corollaries actually) of Nayakama's lemma).

Thus, $\dim_{R/P} (M \otimes R/P) = k$

Since $F = R^k$, we have $F \otimes R/P \simeq (R/P)^k$ and $\dim_{R/P} (F \otimes R/P) = k = \dim_{R/P} (M \otimes R/P)$.

Seeing all morphisms from the exact sequence you mentioned as linear maps between $R/P$-vector spaces, by **equality of dimension**, $F \otimes R/P \longrightarrow M \otimes R/P$ is an isomorphism, thus **injective** and $K \otimes R/P = 0$.

Using **Nayakama's lemma** again, $K = 0$ and $M$ is free thus flat.